# Are sectopods immune to rockets?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I keep trying to hit a sectopod with either a conventional rocket or the blaster launcher, and every time it looks like I decimate everything around it (unless it's another sectopod), but the alien itself is untouched.

Are they immune to blast damage or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet this is a bug.  I've certainly fried sectopods with rockets before, shredder rockets are especially effective.

Comment: I've seen both Sectopods and Ethereals be randomly "immune" to blaster bomb explosions. Haven't seen it with rockets, but I didn't use them as often before I teched up to blaster bombs. I'm hoping it's just a bug they'll patch out soon.

Comment: Vahlen is probably sick of you not listening to her, so she's resorted to sabotaging your equipment.

Answer (score 8):

Sectopods are not immune to rockets.

However, their interactions therewith are quite buggy.

I believe the bug has something to do with elevation -- try to never fire "down" at a Sectopod with your rockets, or the explosion will stop before it reaches the part that registers damage for them.

What's exceptionally infuriating is when you fire at a sectopod and its drones blow up, but it emerges unscathed.

Comment: well, it's better than their drones also being unscathed...

Answer (score 0):

It's a random bug. Happens more with Sectopods but also occasionally with other aliens. They simply take no explosive damage even if there is nothing between them and the epicentre, on the same level etc. Save and quit to desktop and restart the game. The alien should be susceptible to explosives again.

Comment: I don't think saving and restarting does much. Or at least it's not guaranteed to. I've saved and restarted multiple times in this playthrough. :)

Comment: A restart doesn't seem to help the same shot again, but you can try a different shot.